# Endnote x7: Could not initialize database support

Tags: windows-8.1, endnote

I recently come to Windows 8.1 and after I installed Endnote x7, it keeps giving `Could not initialize database support" when I try to create a new library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done to solve this problem:

1. I uninstalled Endnote completely.
2. Using CCleaner I cleaned registry.
3. Removed directories related to Endnote from `appData`
4. Removed directories related to Endnote from `Documents`
5. Reinstalled Endnote.

Answer (score 0):

[This hyperlink](http://community.thomsonreuters.com/t5/EndNote-General/EndNote-X4-quot-Could-not-initialise-database-error-in-Windows-7/td-p/17753) has supplied three methods to solve this problem, and the contents have been attached as follows.

1. 
Where are the libraries located on the system? If they are being placed in *Program Files*, that could be the problem. Try creating/opening a library in the user's Documents folder or their Desktop and see if the issue continues.

Starting with Windows Vista, Windows will not allow you to directly modify files in Program Files. If you try to modify, add, or delete files in Program Files, Windows will work with shadow copies of the files hidden elsewhere on the system which can cause errors like this.

2. 
To solve the problem, change the Endnote preferences as follows. This should work.

1. Open Endnote.
2. From the top bar menu, select *Edit* -> *Preferences*.
3. Click on "Libraries" on the left-hand column.
4. Against "When Endnote starts", open the pull-down menu and then select "Open the specified libraries". (DO NOT click on the button for "Add open libraries" or "Remove Library".)
5. Click on the *Apply* button.
6. Click on the *OK* button.

3. 
This issue is usually either caused by permissions for the location where you are trying to create or open a library, or an issue with a running process on the machine. The easiest way to tell is to restart the machine. 90% of the time this will fix the issue. If it does not, try temporarily disabling any antivirus to see if you continue to have the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I realize that this question is already answered but what I did was open the Endnote installer and click "repair". Seemed to have fixed all of the issues with the database-related errors.

Comment: If it worked, it's good enough to mention.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).